# SQL query to find common items within the lists of columns between a table and specified criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

Because I read that using a query within a loop is not a good idea, I’m     looking for a way to use JOINs and GROUP by, etc instead.  I am not sure if it can be done.

I have a table with different users and their corresponding columns that contain lists of favorite items within different categories. For instance:

```
Column 1 : usernames
Column 2 :  Food - contains a list of the user’s favorite food
Column 3 : Sports - contains a list of the user’s favorite sports
Column 4 : Music - contains a list of the user’s favorite music
```

Now let’s say I already have criteria that I want to know if it’s matched for all of the columns:

```
Column 2 :  contains any of the following: peaches, pears, apples
Column 3 : contains any of the following: football, baseball,   basketball
Column 4 : contains any of the following: jazz, rock
```

My question is: is it possible to generate a SQL query that can tell me  the user and the user’s common items for each column?  I want to know how many items the user matched within each column and also what are the names of the items that were matched for every column. If this is possible, what sort of steps would you take to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: The first step, if possible, is to normalize your database. I.e. no lists in a column, but atomic values for each row/column combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is called [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You would have

```
Table Users
ID    Name
1     John
2     Bea

Table Sport
ID    NameOfTheGame
1     Hockey
2     Football

Table Food
ID    Dishname
1     Spaghetti
2     Apples


Table SportPrefs
ID    FK_ID_Users  FK_ID_Sport
1     1            2            # John preferes Football
2     1            1            #      and hockey
3     2            2            # Bea only hocky 


Table FoodPrefs 
ID    FK_ID_Users  FK_ID_Sport
....  ...           ...
```

You can then query it

```
select * 
from Users 
join SportPrefs on Users.Id == SportPrefs.FK_ID_Users
join Sport on SportPrefs.FK_ID_Sport == Sport.ID
WHERE ....
```

Storing "comma seperated" or whatever lists of things inside columns is usually a bad idea when handling SQL-bases Databases - joining / querying and editing gets complicated that way - think about what to do if someone suddenly dislikes one of his 20 favoured dishes and you have to edit that out of a long list of text.

Datenormalization helps the Database to build nice indexes to get fast results - and helps your sanity as your sql is easier to handle then with stringoperations inside of it.

Edit:

There are several ways to model data (and also of DataNormalization).

You could also model it like this:

```
Table WhatIsIt
ID    Name
1     Sport
2     Food
3     Music

Table WhatUserLikes
ID    FK_ID_WhatIsIT    FK_ID_Users  Description
1     1                 2            Handball
2     1                 2            Golf
3     2                 2            Burgers
4     2                 2            Icecream
5     2                 2            Yellyfish
6     3                 1            ABBA
....
```

To geht what this does is slightly more complex then having distinct tables for Food, Sport and Music though (which I probably would prefere)